# Is there a way to generate ant file local.properties without overwriting build.xml?

Tags: android, ant

I've generated ant build.xml for my android project, using `android update project --name <project_name> --target <target_ID> --path path/to/your/project/` 
(according to http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html) and then modified my build.xml (some custom code is there). So my build.xml is in the VCS.

But in order to perform a build I need local.properties file, which is also generated by `android update project` and so build.xml gets overwritten.

local.properties is not to be checked into the VCS.

Is there a way to only generate the local.properties so that developers (or a build server) can check out the code and build the project using build.xml from VCS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Do not put local.properties into the VCS: generate it whenever it does not exist already (after a clean checkout, for instance), by running

```
android update project -p .
```

so android can generate it with the right path to the sdk. ant.properties or project.properties are meant to be put in VCS with whatever you need fixed on every possible build environment.

If you do not want the build.xml to be modified, change the version-tag entry to something different to its default value, which is 1. For instance:

```
<!-- version-tag: custom -->
```

If you have a look at the build.xml comments, it states that by saying:

```
 ***********************
 ****** IMPORTANT ******
 ***********************
     In all cases you must update the value of version-tag below to read 'custom' instead of an integer,
     in order to avoid having your file be overridden by tools such as "android update project"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if only path parameter is specified (for example `android update project --path .` when called from the project directory) only **local.properties** and **proguard.cfg** files are updated.

Comment: ... clobbering proguard.cfg is a bit of a problem.

Comment: `android update project --path .` There was a misprinting in the answer. Please fix it. The command is right.

Answer (score 1):

Given that it (in general) only contains a single property, `sdk.dir`, pointing to the developer's Android SDK root, I'm inclined to say that it's not asking too much for the developers to just create it by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but actually I had this problem on our build server, so it's a bit problematic to ask it to create the file without telling how to do that :) Of course I could have created the file and than just copied it to the project file from somewhere, but as we may have several build slaves I want to make it easier to configure. Anyway `andorid update project --path .` works pretty fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, I completely glossed over where you said "or a build server" when I'd written my answer.