# Error: Uh oh! ENOENT, no such file or directory '<meteor-app>/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/local.properties'

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, meteor

while trying to run a meteor **android** app (`meteor run android`) with the following [Cordova location-services plugin](https://github.com/louisbl/cordova-plugin-locationservices) I get: 

`Error: Uh oh!
ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/yonatan/snipitest/meteor-test-app/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/local.properties'`

if I try `meteor run` there is no error.

Comment: what happens when you try to run a bare-bones meteor app on android? do you get the same error? Also, do you have a mobile-config.js file?

Comment: I don't know all the details of this particular plugin but Cordova is for the Android build so it makes sense it does not show an error when running just meteor run.

Comment: Have you checked that file actually exists? It looks like when you are running `metetor run android` it assumes files exist under `platforms/android`, where as the other does not.

Comment: Have you tried generating it yourself?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790286/is-there-a-way-to-local.propertiesgenerate-ant-file-local-properties-without-overwriting-build-x

Comment: have you installed the android sdk and run `meteor add-platform android` in your meteor project? Also, can you provide the results from `meteor list`

Comment: Have you set up your file permissions? Of you use meteor in sudo then often ownership and/or permission of a crucial file gets changed.

Answer (score 2):

Meteor and Cordova are kinda frenemies.

Make sure you run `meteor add-platform android` and install everything like described [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-integration)

It works.  I'm using it.  It's just alot of code from alot of different people coming together.

You can also delete `[project_dir]/.meteor/local` to clean up anything left over from a broken build.